# How To Create A New List of Tuple From One List

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

```
sampleList = ['CustomerA', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'CustomerB', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'CustomerC', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No']

Preferred Output : [('CustomerA', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'), ('CustomerB', 'No', 'No', 'No'), ('CustomerC', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No')]
```

I wanted to create a list tuple from just one list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```py
sampleList = [
    'CustomerA', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 
    'CustomerB', 'No', 'No', 'No', 
    'CustomerC', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No'
]
preferredOutput = [
    tuple(sampleList[n : n + 4]) 
    for n in range(0, len(sampleList), 4)
]
print(preferredOutput)

# OUTPUT (IN PRETTY FORM)
# 
# [
#     ('CustomerA', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'), 
#     ('CustomerB', 'No', 'No', 'No'), 
#     ('CustomerC', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No')
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension `output=[tuple(sampleList[4*i:4*i+4]) for i in range(3)]`